# Lagged variables in panels with ddply

Tags: r, panel, plyr, data.table, lag

I'm trying to generate precision change (based on estimated confidence intervals) in what is in essence a panel data set.

So as a simple example here's the function I've written and applying it to a non-sensical example....

```
precision.gain <- function(x){
  x        <- ts(x, start=x[1])
  x.length <- seq(length = length(x))
  x.lag    <- lag(x, -1)
  x.gain   <- ((x - x.lag) * 100) / x
  x.gain   <- c(NA, x.gain)
  x.gain
}
t <- data.frame(x=1:20)
t <- cbind(t, precision.gain(t$x))
t
x precision.gain(t$x)
1   1                  NA
2   2           50.000000
3   3           33.333333
4   4           25.000000
5   5           20.000000 
6   6           16.666667
7   7           14.285714
8   8           12.500000
9   9           11.111111
10 10           10.000000
11 11            9.090909
12 12            8.333333
13 13            7.692308
14 14            7.142857
15 15            6.666667
16 16            6.250000
17 17            5.882353
18 18            5.555556
19 19            5.263158
20 20            5.000000
```

That works and is great, but I'm having trouble (or more likely mis-understanding) how to then (t?)apply this to my data frame a sample of which is....

```
subset(results.normal.sum, n2 > 20 & n2 < 30, select=c(sd2, n2, ci.width1))
    sd2 n2 ci.width1
11  0.4 22 0.6528714
12  0.4 24 0.6167015
13  0.4 26 0.5895856
14  0.4 28 0.5658297
46  0.6 22 0.6529126
47  0.6 24 0.6196544
48  0.6 26 0.5922061
49  0.6 28 0.5642688
81  0.8 22 0.6513849
82  0.8 24 0.6194468
83  0.8 26 0.5923094
84  0.8 28 0.5636396
116 1.0 22 0.6522927
117 1.0 24 0.6191043
118 1.0 26 0.5900129
119 1.0 28 0.5652429
151 1.2 22 0.6518072
152 1.2 24 0.6193353
153 1.2 26 0.5892683
154 1.2 28 0.5632235
186 1.4 22 0.6527031
187 1.4 24 0.6191458
188 1.4 26 0.5899453
189 1.4 28 0.5640431
221 1.6 22 0.6521401
222 1.6 24 0.6191883
223 1.6 26 0.5893458
224 1.6 28 0.5637215
256 1.8 22 0.6512491
257 1.8 24 0.6180401
258 1.8 26 0.5905810
259 1.8 28 0.5647388
291 2.0 22 0.6515769
292 2.0 24 0.6183121
293 2.0 26 0.5896990
294 2.0 28 0.5663394
```

I've tried using ddply() from Hadley Wickham's plyr package.....

```
ddply(results.normal.sum, .(sd2), precision.gain, x=ci.width1)
Error in .fun(piece, ...) : unused argument(s) (piece)
```

Using tapply() directly I sort of get there, but it doesn't return a data frame which can be cbind()....

```
> tapply(results.normal.sum$ci.width1, sd2, precision.gain)
$`0.4`
 [1]          NA -771.332292  -68.852635  -30.514545  -19.877447  -14.515380
 [7]  -11.147183   -9.282641   -7.680418   -6.836209   -5.954992   -5.865053
[13]   -4.599158   -4.198409   -4.155838   -3.529773   -3.590234   -3.432364
[19]   -2.899601   -3.092533   -2.721967   -2.506706   -2.498318   -2.321500
[25]   -2.299822   -2.187855   -2.116990   -1.896162   -1.853487   -1.604902
[31]   -2.194138   -1.473042   -1.710051   -1.701994   -1.417754

$`0.6`
 [1]          NA -756.196418  -68.222048  -30.566420  -19.216860  -15.162929
 [7]  -10.645899   -9.628775   -7.326799   -7.178820   -5.770681   -5.367216
[13]   -4.634938   -4.951049   -3.949776   -3.761633   -3.326209   -3.387764
[19]   -3.009317   -3.074398   -2.397660   -2.678573   -2.626077   -2.268373
[25]   -2.426720   -1.956498   -2.119986   -1.859410   -1.992678   -1.707448
[31]   -1.991583   -1.595951   -1.765913   -1.415065   -1.655725
....
```

I feel like I'm close but am missing or have misunderstood something.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397771/r-data-table-grouping-for-lagged-regression) but just do not understand the answer/solution provided.

Thanks in advance for any help,

slackline

Comment: OK, I can see what you have tried, but I can't tell what you're trying to do. Please post the expected results, given your sample data.

Comment: @Andrie, What I'm after is shown in the first non-sensical example, the percentage change between each observation.  In my real data.frame I wish to do this _within_ each grouping of sd2 which is why I tried using ddply() and then tapply()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I guessed correctly what you need, the following is a solution that exploits the handy `:=` operator in `data.table`.

First read the sample data:

```
testData <- textConnection("sd2 n2 ci.width1
11  0.4 22 0.6528714
12  0.4 24 0.6167015
13  0.4 26 0.5895856
14  0.4 28 0.5658297
46  0.6 22 0.6529126
47  0.6 24 0.6196544
48  0.6 26 0.5922061
49  0.6 28 0.5642688
81  0.8 22 0.6513849
82  0.8 24 0.6194468
83  0.8 26 0.5923094
84  0.8 28 0.5636396
116 1.0 22 0.6522927
117 1.0 24 0.6191043
118 1.0 26 0.5900129
119 1.0 28 0.5652429
151 1.2 22 0.6518072
152 1.2 24 0.6193353
153 1.2 26 0.5892683
154 1.2 28 0.5632235
186 1.4 22 0.6527031
187 1.4 24 0.6191458
188 1.4 26 0.5899453
189 1.4 28 0.5640431
221 1.6 22 0.6521401
222 1.6 24 0.6191883
223 1.6 26 0.5893458
224 1.6 28 0.5637215
256 1.8 22 0.6512491
257 1.8 24 0.6180401
258 1.8 26 0.5905810
259 1.8 28 0.5647388
291 2.0 22 0.6515769
292 2.0 24 0.6183121
293 2.0 26 0.5896990
294 2.0 28 0.5663394")
```

Then, put the data in a `data.table` and ...

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(read.table(testData, header = TRUE))
dt[, list(n2, ci.width1, prec.gain = precision.gain(ci.width1)), by = sd2]
```

Here is the output

```
> dt[, list(n2, ci.width1, prec.gain = precision.gain(ci.width1)), by = sd2]
   sd2 n2 ci.width1 prec.gain
   0.4 22 0.6528714        NA
   0.4 24 0.6167015 -5.865058
   0.4 26 0.5895856 -4.599146
   0.4 28 0.5658297 -4.198419
   0.6 22 0.6529126        NA
   0.6 24 0.6196544 -5.367218
   0.6 26 0.5922061 -4.634924
   0.6 28 0.5642688 -4.951062
   0.8 22 0.6513849        NA
   0.8 24 0.6194468 -5.155907
   0.8 26 0.5923094 -4.581626
   0.8 28 0.5636396 -5.086548
     1 22 0.6522927        NA
     1 24 0.6191043 -5.360712
     1 26 0.5900129 -4.930638
     1 28 0.5652429 -4.382187
   1.2 22 0.6518072        NA
   1.2 24 0.6193353 -5.243024
   1.2 26 0.5892683 -5.102430
   1.2 28 0.5632235 -4.624239
   1.4 22 0.6527031        NA
   1.4 24 0.6191458 -5.419935
   1.4 26 0.5899453 -4.949696
   1.4 28 0.5640431 -4.592238
   1.6 22 0.6521401        NA
   1.6 24 0.6191883 -5.321774
   1.6 26 0.5893458 -5.063666
   1.6 28 0.5637215 -4.545560
   1.8 22 0.6512491        NA
   1.8 24 0.6180401 -5.373276
   1.8 26 0.5905810 -4.649506
   1.8 28 0.5647388 -4.575956
     2 22 0.6515769        NA
     2 24 0.6183121 -5.379937
     2 26 0.5896990 -4.852153
     2 28 0.5663394 -4.124664
cn sd2 n2 ci.width1 prec.gain
```

Comment: I guess OP wants that too, but combined with an i subset, or group by, or both (since OP tried ddply)

Comment: Thats sort of close, but I'm expecting there to be NA under prec.gain each time there is a new value for sd2 and all other values for prec.gain to be non-zero.  I'll have a look at the data.table package though not come across it before, thanks @RYogi

Comment: Slackline, it is still no clear to me what you are expecting exactly. See my edit: `precision.gain` is now applied to the column `ci.width1` grouping the data by `sd2`.

Comment: @RYogi : thats the nail hit on the head, thanks. Spent some time yesterday trying to get my head around data.tables, not made it yet (& have diminishing time to get this work done now).