# Creating T-1 variable | R

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data, plm

I would like to create a new variable `sales.T.minus.1` which will present the value of sales from year - 1. I created a replicable example below:

```
  library(plm)
  library(dplyr)

  data <- pdata.frame(Cigar)
    
  data("Cigar")
    
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(sales.T.minus.1 = lag(sales, 1))
```

Unfortunately this code is not working. The value in variable sales.T.minus.1 is the same as in variable sales.

| year | sales | sales.T.minus.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 95.4 | 95.4 |

How can I achieve the result I want?

The result I want is:

| year | sales | sales.T.minus.1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 64 | 95.4 | 93.9 |
| 65 | 98.5 | 95.4 |

Comment: Could you please explain what is not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: We can't really tell what result you get or what result you want from what you've presented.  Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the desired result.

Comment: Also, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604591/create-lag-lead-and-diff-variables-in-plm-dataframe) will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Try grouping by `state`. `mutate(sales.T.minus.1 = lag(sales, 2), .by = state)`. Also, first load the data, then coerce to class `'pdata.frame'`. (wrong instructions order in your code.)

Comment: @Quinten I edited my post, I think it is more reproducible :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `dplyr::lag` because there may be some conflicting functions across package you have installed. And you want to use lag 1 instead of 2. When running it should work like this:

```r
library(plm)
library(dplyr)

data("Cigar")

data <- pdata.frame(Cigar)

data <- data %>%
  mutate(sales.T.minus.1 = dplyr::lag(sales, 1))
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

if lag function doesnt work, then you can use shift function from data.table, it is faster than dplyr/lag

```
library(plm)
library(data.table)

data <- pdata.frame(Cigar)

data("Cigar")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(sales.T.minus.1 = data.table::shift(sales, n = 2, fill = NA))
```